# Why do I need a compiler to build a Python only conda package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Why do I need a C/C++ compiler to build a Python only conda package? What gets actually compiled to a binary in this case?

Comment: Some Python modules are really built from C or C++ code for efficiency reasons. If the Conda package itself doesn't have any such modules then maybe it depends on such a module?

Comment: This is just a basic question on that topic. I plan to put my personal "standard library" of self written helpers into a conda package to make it available over different environments. So i wondered why i would need a compiler here. Its clear that i need to use it if there is any C dependency. So: As soon as numpy is used i will need a compiler or is it still sufficient to use the already installed package in my environment?

Comment: What makes you think you need one? What steps are you taking to build your conda package (including content of meta.yml and build.sh), what errors do you get?

Comment: Just from the [docs](https://conda.io/docs/build_tutorials/windows.html#the-toolkit)

Comment: I don't see why a compiler should be necessary for a pure python build, so I would recommend trying to do a build without having a compiler installed.